Audin's claim on Seifert manifolds, and generalization to orbifolds
In Audin's book on symplectic torus actions, she states the following proposition:

Proposition I.3.8: Let $W$ be an oriented Seifert manifold. Let $n$ be a common multiple of the orders of the exceptional orbits. The manifold $W'$, quotient of $W$ by the $\mathbb{Z}/n$-action, is endowed with an action of $S^1/(\mathbb{Z}/n) \cong S^1$ which is both effective and principal.

She then uses this proposition to give an alternative definition to the Seifert Euler number.
My questions are as follows:

Are the proposition and this specific definition of the Seifert Euler number both due to Audin? Do they appear in any other source?
Are there any generalizations of this claim to more general orbibundles? In particular, was the trick of taking a quotient of an orbibundle, and getting a smooth bundle (or more accurately, a topological one for which we can choose a smooth structure) been used by other authors for orbibundles?

My motivation for question (1) is that I have not seen this definition of Seifert Euler number elsewhere, and I wondered how non-standard it is. My motivation for question (2) is that the proof of the proposition didn't seem very specific for Seifert fibrations, and so I wondered if this result is also applicable in a more general setting.
Edit: To clarify, in Audin's proposition, the manifold $W$ is of dimension $3$.
Citation:

M. Audin: Torus Actions on Symplectic Manifolds. Second revised edition. Progress in Mathematics, 93. Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel, 2004.

